# Problem with Numerical integration due to singularity

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to solve an integral numerically in Mathematica. The integrand is

```
x^2/((1-x^4)Sqrt[xm^4(1-xm^4)-x^4(1-x^4)]),
```

with lower limits: `x = xm`, and upper limit `x = Infinity`. Where `xm=((1+Sqrt[1-a^2])/2)^(1/4)` and `a` is any constant lets say `a=0.2`.

Using `NIntegrate` in Mathematica I got an error

> "Integrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 50 \
>   recursive bisections in x near {x} = \
>   {1.0000000000000000010207139609231930075006998480154358397633601823358\ 2911765290712976879587123209719525842623480662534192183469748716277627\
>   1045933514870560125091416879336103379976452739253556510672066452891154\
>   3397372398189215735216474671862275042165790}."

Can anybody please explain to me what is the main problem here, and how to minimize the above error massage and find the correct answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide your Mathematica code? Thanks

Comment: I am using this code:  CV[a_?NumberQ] := 
 NIntegrate[(
  a  x^2)/(\[Pi] (1 - x^4) Sqrt[
   1/2 (1 + Sqrt[1 - a^2]) (1 + 1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[1 - a^2])) - 
    x^4 (1 - x^4)]), {x, ((1 + Sqrt[1 - a^2])/2)^(1/(
   n - 1)), ((1 + Sqrt[1 - a^2])/2)^(1/(n - 1)), Infinity}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 50]

Comment: Just edit your question, please. If you indent 4 characters one can "see" mathematica code for further use.

Comment: The main problem seems to be a singularity of the integrand `x->xm`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, yes.

Answer (score 2):

To long for a comment...

Using `PrincipalValue` proposed by `user64494` directly

```
NIntegrate[x^2/((1 - x^4) Sqrt[xm^4 (1 - xm^4) - x^4 (1 - x^4)]), {x, xm,Infinity} , Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> {1, xm}]
(*0.663908*)
```

gives the desired result for the integral!

Comment: Thanks :). It works.

Answer (score 1):

This is an imroper integral over an infinite ray and the integrand has  singularities at `x==1` and at  `x==xm`. Moreover, there exists its principal value only because of the singularity at `x==1`. The following works.

```
a = 0.2;xm = ((1 + Sqrt[1 - a^2])/2)^(1/4)
```

> 0.997465B

We split the integral into two items:

```
NIntegrate[x^2/((1 - x^4) Sqrt[xm^4 (1 - xm^4) - x^4 (1 - x^4)]), {x,xm, 5}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 35, Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> {1}]+
 NIntegrate[x^2/((1-x^4) Sqrt[xm^4 (1 - xm^4) - x^4 (1 - x^4)]),{x,5,Infinity},
WorkingPrecision ->35, AccuracyGoal -> 5, Method -> "GlobalAdaptive"]
```

> 0.6639079212365501863627942458541675 - 
>    2.863389453924790530558107241*10^-7 I

Addition. In response to the Ulrich Neumann's comment, let us consider

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Series[x^2/((1 - x^4)*Sqrt[xm^4*(1 - xm^4) - x^4 (1 - x^4)]),{x, xm,1}, Assumptions->x > xm]
```

> $$-\frac{\text{xm}^2}{2 \left(\left(\text{xm}^4-1\right) \sqrt{\text{xm}^3 \left(2 \text{xm}^4-1\right)}\right) \sqrt{x-\text{xm}}}+\frac{\left(30 \text{xm}^9-9 \text{xm}^5-5 \text{xm}\right) \sqrt{x-\text{xm}}}{8 \left(\text{xm}^4-1\right)^2 \left(2 \text{xm}^4-1\right) \sqrt{\text{xm}^3 \left(2 \text{xm}^4-1\right)}}+O\left((x-\text{xm})^{3/2}\right) $$

and

```
Series[x^2/((1 - x^4) Sqrt[xm^4 (1 - xm^4) - x^4 (1 - x^4)]), {x,Infinity, 2}]
```

> $ O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^6\right)$

Therefore, the integral under consideration converges.

Comment: No it doesn't converge. If you change WorkingPrecision you get other results.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: Many thanks from me to you for your valuable comment. I based the convergence and corrected the value.

Comment: @user64494: The result highly fluctuates by changing the WorkingPrecision to a different value using your method.

Comment: @rickys: Thank you. I noticed that the integral exists only as its principal value and modified my answer.

Comment: @user64494: Thank you. Your method looks correct. However, I am still getting error massages like "umerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the \
following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly \
oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small" and "Integrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive \
bisections in x near {x} = \
{0.9893969440678009985342603407569055059763366930099597753813067236204\
795125147518581737}". Do you know how to avoid these massages? Do these massages indicate serious problems in the result?

Comment: @user64494: Tricky solution idea. By the way you don't need to set precision. `NIntegrate[x^2/((1 - x^4) Sqrt[xm^4 (1 - xm^4) - x^4 (1 - x^4)]), {x, xm, 5} , 
  Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> {1, xm}] + 
 NIntegrate[ x^2/((1 - x^4) Sqrt[xm^4 (1 - xm^4) - x^4 (1 - x^4)]), {x, 5,Infinity}, Method -> "GlobalAdaptive"] (*0.663908 *)`

Comment: @rickys: Sorry,  I obtain no communication in version 11.3. Can you support your claim by  an nb file with the executed code (eg through Dropbox) as solid people use to do?

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: The French call it  "staircase wit".

Comment: @rickys I get the error in 11.3 if `a = 0.2` (machine precision) but not if `a = 1/5`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gbvpC.png